# Upgrade Pylint Version 1.9.2 to latest Version

Tags: python, upgrade, updates, pylint, linter

I'm using VS Code and it's Python Extension installed the linter Pylint 1.9.2 by default. However, It is highlighting some bugs/errors in my code which on execution worked correctly. A simple example:

```
class Point:
```

> F0002:: generator raised StopIteration

While searching to resolve that issue, I found that it requires to upgrade/update the pylint to the latest version (Currently 2.2). I tired several commands on Git Bash terminal but no luck. The commands were

> pip install pylint
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pylint in c:\users\noor muhammad\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (1.9.2)
>
> which pylint
>
> which: no pylint in (/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Noor Muhammad/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Users/Noor Muhammad/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts:/c/Users/Noor Muhammad/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32:/c/Users/Noor Muhammad/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Noor Muhammad/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/pip/**main**.py)

I tired pip documentation but I wasn't able to find how to update the linter to the latest version.

Edit: The pip list is as follows:

> astroid           1.6.5
>   colorama          0.3.9
>   isort             4.3.4
>   lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1
>   mccabe            0.6.1
>   pip               18.0
>   pylint            1.9.2
>   setuptools        39.0.1
>   six               1.11.0
>   wrapt             1.10.11

A help would be really appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:

I went to the dictionary:

> c:\users******\appdata\roaming\python\python37

and delete the site-package folder. then, the command:

```
python -m pip install pylint
```

took the rest.

P.S: Mod, please mark the solution as solved